# Rotating an Image in a MapQuickItem around its center

Tags: qt, qml

I am using a [`MapQuickItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-mapquickitem.html) with an [`Image`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html) as [`sourceItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-mapquickitem.html#sourceItem-prop) to display the user's location on a QML [`Map`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-map.html).

The documentation for `MapQuickItem` states that:

> The set coordinate will line up with the top-left corner of the
>   contained item when shown on the screen.
>
> The [`anchorPoint`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-mapquickitem.html#anchorPoint-prop) property provides a way to line up the
>   coordinate with other parts of the item than just the top-left
>   corner, by setting a number of pixels the item will be offset by.
>
> A simple way to think about it is to note that the point given by
>   [`anchorPoint`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-mapquickitem.html#anchorPoint-prop) on the item itself is the point that will line up
>   with the given [`coordinate`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-mapquickitem.html#coordinate-prop) when displayed.

So I have set the anchor point to match the center of the image like this:

```
anchorPoint.x: img.width/2
anchorPoint.y: img.height/2
```

This places the center of the arrow right above the user's location. So far so good.

Now, I wish to rotate the image around its center to show the user's heading using the [`rotation`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#rotation-prop) property.

The documentation for the `Item` [`transformOrigin`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#transformOrigin-prop) property states that:

> Nine transform origins are available, as shown in the image below. The
>   default transform origin is `Item.Center`.
>
> [image: Transform Origin]

Thus I expect the image to rotate around its center, since this is the default behavior.

But unfortunately, the reality is very different. The rotation is applied around the top-left corner of the image, moving the arrow away from the user's location, as shown in the following image:

[image: Rotating MapQuickItem]

- Was my interpretation of the documentation wrong?
- How can I make the image rotate around its center?

---

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Window {
    width: 512
    height: 512
    visible: true

    property variant loc: QtPositioning.coordinate(48.858222, 2.2945)

    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: Plugin { name: "osm" }
        center: loc
        zoomLevel: 16

        MapQuickItem {
            id: arrow
            coordinate: loc

            anchorPoint.x: img.width/2
            anchorPoint.y: img.height/2

            sourceItem: Image {
                id: img
                NumberAnimation on rotation { from: 0; to: 360; duration: 2000; loops: Animation.Infinite; }
                source: "arrow.png"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**arrow.png**: https://pasteboard.co/HYgV7Nf.png

Comment: I was just reading new SO questions and got really frustrated by the extremely low quality of questions recently. And then I saw yours. Nicely formatted with graphs and images, examples and explanations. And while the solution is really simple, damn is it a really nice question. +1 from me.

Comment: @ItayGrudev Thank you very much Itay! I do take my time to write my questions. Thank you for stopping by. I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is correct, the problem is the order of how the tasks are applied, what you are doing is to rotate the image first, and then you just establish the MapQuickItem source that uses the topleft as a point of reference, so it will always rotate with respect to topLeft.

The solution is to rotate the MapQuickItem instead of the sourceItem:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Window {
    width: 512
    height: 512
    visible: true

    property variant loc: QtPositioning.coordinate(48.858222, 2.2945)

    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: Plugin { name: "osm" }
        center: loc
        zoomLevel: 16

        MapQuickItem {
            id: arrow
            coordinate: loc
            NumberAnimation on rotation { from: 0; to: 360; duration: 2000; loops: Animation.Infinite; }
            anchorPoint.x: img.width/2
            anchorPoint.y: img.height/2
            sourceItem: Image {
                id: img
                source: "arrow.png"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Edwin! This is a great example where the order of operations does affect the final result! :)